# array initialized to "None" in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I see a piece of python code

```
/*Constructor*/
self.matrix={}

/*my funciton*/
if(self.matrix.get((packet.src,packet.dst))==None):
```

does a python array get initialized to None? What does none represent ? Is the above comparision correct?I am a newbie in python and trying to relate to C++ concepts

Comment: `get()` is a dictionary method that will return `None` if the key (and associated value) are not present in the dictionary, otherwise it returns the value. `None` is used a little like `NULL` is in C/C++.

Comment: Not only are there no arrays in Python, you don't have a constructor in your code either. You do create an empty `dict` though.

Comment: You should also note that comments in python begin with `#`... `/* */` is a syntax error in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.matrix` isn't an array, it is a `dict`. This is comparable to a `std::map` in C++. From your usage, it is like a `std::map<std::pair<srcType, dstType>, valueType>`. (Note that `dict`s can hold variant types both in the key and the value -- I'm only assuming that it'll always use a `tuple` of 2 elements as the key.)

And no, `self.matrix` isn't initialized to `None`. `dict.get()` *returns* `None` if it can't find a match. As an alternative, `[]` throws a `KeyError` exception if it can't find a match.

Comment: excellent answer.this is exactly the way I wanted it. :)Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`matrix` is a dictionary not a list. This is best explained by an example:

```
>>> dic = {}
>>> dic['a'] = 1
>>> dic['a']
1
>>> dic.get('a')
1
>>> dic.get('b') == None
True
>>> dic['b']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    dic['b']
KeyError: 'b'
```

Answer (score 1):

An empty list or dictionary in Python (Python programs don't generally use arrays, although there is a module for them) are "empty list object" and "empty dictionary object", respectively, not None. The get() function returns None as a way of saying "the dictionary doesn't contain a value for that key".  None is a constant value that is not equal to any scalar value (like integers, strings, etc.) or any instance of any class.  It's just what it says--this is not a thing. C/C++ has no such concept for scalar types like ints and floats, but a NULL pointer is guaranteed to be unequal to any valid pointer to an object.

In the OOP model, None is a subclass of every class, but Python doesn't really care that much since it's more loosely typed.